# How to obtain vertices of sphereGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

Ok a lot of you might laugh since it seems really easy question, but what i would like to do is place some objects on top of vertices of sphere (yes it might sound strange but in Three.js each sphere consists of small triangles, and those corners/vertices locations are of my interest, random places on sphere are not an option)

My code which does not work:

```
var sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 80, 16, 8 );
console.log(sphereGeometry.geometry.vertices.length);
```

second line throws an error "sphereGeometry.geometry is undefined" -> sounds strange to me since sphereGeometry seems to inherit a lot of stuff from geometry, nonetheless i have no idea how to get coordinates of each vertex. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, sphereGeometry already IS THE Three.Geometry-Object. So for getting the vertices, you do

```
   console.log(sphereGeometry.vertices.length);
```

Or you reference the Three.Mesh to your variable named "sphereGeometry" although that would be wrong from a naming convention point of view but then, your above statement would work^^